# Replacement of WinForm WebBrower in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use function from winform Project to my WPF Project, but the code seems not work with WPF or the structure of WPF. After many hours research I figured out that this code only work for winfowm. I really need to use it to print to thermal printer and I'm using to print html because my printer in this case will print Arabic characters.

Here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    StartBrowser(xx); 
}

public static void StartBrowser(string source)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
        webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted1;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = source;

        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}
static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    webBrowser.SetBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);       
    webBrowser.Print();        
}
```

Is there any other way to print HTML like this using WPF?

Comment: `WebBrowser` is obsolete. Please migrate to `WebView2`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

Comment: You create a background thread, but WebBrowser is designed to run on UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work as written in WPF, as well as it does in WinForms anyway...

First, add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

Then qualify everything...

```
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;

public static void StartBrowser(string source)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var webBrowser = new WinForms.WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
        webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted1;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = source;

        WinForms.Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted1(object sender, WinForms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WinForms.WebBrowser)sender;
    webBrowser.SetBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webBrowser.Print();

}
```

Comment: Yes it actually works well, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar using `WebView2`. However, this method doesn't replicate the current behaviour exactly. The WebView2 control needs to be added to the UI before it will be fully initialized.

Follow the steps in [Get started with WebView2 in WPF apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf):

1. Make sure you have the [WebView2 runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) installed
2. Add the WebView2 control to your window/page/control:

   ```
   <DockPanel>
       <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
           <Button x:Name="PopulateWebView2" 
                   Click="PopulateWebView2_Click" 
                   Content="Print"/>
       </DockPanel>
       <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView2" />
   </DockPanel>
   ```
3. Initialize WebView2, and call this in the window/page constructor:

   ```
   void InitializeAsync()
   {
       webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
   }
   ```
4. Handle the button click and print the page.

   ```
   private void PopulateWebView2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       webView2.NavigateToString(xx); // your html string to populate the browser
       webView2.NavigationCompleted += async (s, e) =>
       {
           await webView2.CoreWebView2.PrintToPdfAsync(@"Path/To/file.pdf");
       };
   }
   ```

As mentioned, the WebView2 control needs to be rendered on the UI before it can be fully initialized. This will print the page as a PDF file to the path specified in `PrintToPdfAsync(path)`.

You could use the built-in print dialog and use the DOM to execute a print command instead using the following command, however that will require input from the user to select the file location:

```
await webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();")
```

Comment: Your solution works and compatible with WPF, I tried it and it's working well! I appreciate that!